# SQL in Python 3.0?

Tags: python, sql

How to use any SQL database eg. mysql, pgsql or other except the ones Python has built-in support for?

```
def example():
  con= Mysql("root", blablabla)
  con->query("SELECT * bla bla bla")
....
```

Answer (score 3):

What DB and what extension are you using? For `sqlite3` (and any other extension compatible with DB-API 2.0) you can use something like [this](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/example')
c = conn.cursor()

# Create table
c.execute('''create table stocks(date text, trans text, symbol text, qty real, price real)''')

# Insert a row of data
c.execute("""insert into stocks values ('2006-01-05','BUY','RHAT',100,35.14)""")

# Save (commit) the changes
conn.commit()

# We can also close the cursor if we are done with it
c.close()
```

BTW, there is no `->`in Python

Answer (score 0):

There is a list of Python 3.x compatible packages here:  http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all

All I could find was [oursql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/oursql/0.9.2) and [py-postgresql](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-postgresql/1.0.1)